# How to adapt text and/or elements size while designing to smaller screens?

Tags: user-interface, responsive-design, adobe, user-experience

I have a personal project designed for the desktop that I previously created in Adobe XD, and now I would like to put it on Behance. To do so, I need to adapt the layout, designed for the desktop, to mobile.

I don't usually design for smaller screens, so I am wondering how much I need to decrease text and element sizes? For example, if I have a text with a font size of `40px`, what calculations should I use to decrease the size for mobile? Is there a default percentage to reduce desktop values? Alternatively, are there visual rules that other designers follow?

I always design for Bootstrap, but I'm not sure if I am thinking about mobile the right way.

I've also posted this on the User Experience Stack Exchange forum, but I'm not sure which one is the best for my question.

Thank you for sharing your thoughts and advice.

I have designed mostly for desktops as a traditional web designer, and now I'm trying to migrate to UI/UX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern devices do most of the scale conversion work for you by adequately scaling the viewport to compensate for the smaller screens and often higher resolutions. Depending on the type of application you are designing, the technology is different, but the result is very similar.

For example, if you were implementing the design for the Web, you would likely need to use browser features like [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to manage your content.

However, because you are focusing on the design of the site, you should not need to worry about the 'how', so you can focus on what to do.

Here are some tips:

- Elements and text appear roughly the same size on desktop and mobile if you hold the device at a casual but comfortable distance and compare it to the size it appears on your desktop's screen at an average viewing distance. You can try this by going to a website built for mobile like [Apple's](http://apple.com).
- Because of the similar size but reduced screen dimensions, you need to simplify your design, avoid multiple columns (especially for phones).
- Because you see a smaller portion of your design at once on mobile, there is less need for significant visual hierarchy. For example, if you have multiple heading levels with a significant visual size difference on the desktop, you can probably get away with making them closer in size on mobile.
- If you want to see what your design looks like on mobile, try emailing the design to your phone, save it to your pictures, and load the image full screen. You may need to zoom the image in a bit so that the left and right of the design are touching the sides of your phone's screen. If your text looks too small or your elements are too large, adjust the design and load it on your phone again. Keep doing this until you get it right.

With a little practice and effort, you will get the hang of Mobile design. And, if you want to take it to the next level, try researching mobile first design. [Here](https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/a-hands-on-guide-to-mobile-first-design/) is just one of many articles on the subject.

Comment: Actually I'm designing just for the web at the moment. I'm studying UX concepts and processes only to know them, but I need to be good in web first and then thinking about design an app for example. It's a typical question from who is a starter with all this thing called "UI/UX".

Comment: The guidance I gave above will apply for web or native apps from a design perspective. I was only pointing out that how someone codes it may be different, the design process is largely the same.

Comment: Yes, I think as the same as you. Thanks for sharing that link from uxpin, sounds like it will help me a lot!